# iOS 8 programmatic contraints for PageViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, constraints, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController which I am programmatically adding to the current view via the following:

```
    // Create the page view controller.
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homePageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


// Instantiate the first view controller.
UIViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[startingViewController]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     // Completion code
                                 }];

// Add the page view controller to this root view controller.
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This is working well, however I need to add a constraint the this as I have an image view above and I want the top of the PageViewController to attach to the bottom of the ImageView. I have tried:

```
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.headerImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.pageViewController attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

and although the code builds fine, I get and error

```
Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView or subclass'
```

I've also tried:

```
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"view": self.pageViewController.view,
                        @"top": self.headerImage };

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[top][view]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

And although this build and runs without error, the constraint is not observed.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When using layout constraints with the visual format you have: "[view][anotherView]" which is a horizontal layout and "V:[view][anotherView]" which is a vertical layout.

What you want to do is: `[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[top]-[view]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];`

Comment: Great, thanks. That has worked to a certain extent. Although the PageViewController is now "attached" to the bottom of the ImageView. If I navigate away from the view and then navigate back (with embedded Navigation controller) the whole scene shifts upward by the height of the Navigation controller. i.e the header image now appears to be attached to the top of the superview rather than bottom of the navigation bar. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't really offer very constructive advice because it depends on how you've set out all your layout constraints. Constraints are brilliant but if you do one wrong it can spell disaster for your whole view. Look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) for the visual format. Also check all your other constraints.

Comment: Fair comment. Thank you for your responses. I should be well on the way now.